# date no such file or directory

Tags: bash, shell, scripting

I'm trying to script something that isn't outputting quite correctly with the date command. Here's the contents of what I have thus far:

```
#!/bin/bash
# Get RPM manifest
# Output written to /tmp

NOW=$(date +%D)

rpm -qa --qf="%{NAME}.%{ARCH}\n" | sort > /tmp/$HOSTNAME.RPM_Manifest.$NOW.txt
```

When I run this script, I get this message:

```
[root@linmachine1 ~]# sh /usr/local/bin/rpm_manifest.sh
/usr/local/bin/rpm_manifest.sh: line 7: /tmp/linmachine1.RPM_Manifest.03/01/17.txt: No such file or directory
```

I suspect the problem is in how the date formatting within the NOW variable I'm defining may be the culprit.  I've tried with and without quotes and get the same thing.  Looking at the man pages, I didn't see a way to change the default behavior such that the forward slashes would be replaced by dots, as I believe this is where the problem lies.

EDIT:  Thanks for all of your responses.  I'm not real sure why this was downvoted though.  I asked a legitimate question.  What gives?

Comment: As a side note, if you have a `bash` shebang, don't run your program with `sh`. Either make your file executable with `chmod +x` and run it directly, or run it with `bash`

Comment: Just quote the filename: `sort > "/tmp/$HOSTNAME....txt"`

Comment: The error message is pretty explicit -- it's not a problem with `date` at all, but with opening the output file (which happens *before* the shell starts `date`), since it's trying to create `17.txt` in a directory `/tmp/linmachine1.RPM_Manifest.03/01` that doesn't exist.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you shouldn't have slashes in a file name.

Use:

```
now=$(date "+%d.%m.%Y") 

rpm -qa --qf="%{NAME}.%{ARCH}\n" | sort > "/tmp/$HOSTNAME.RPM_Manifest.$now.txt"
```

instead, or replace the `.` with whatever you prefer

Comment: I suppose the extra `date` in `now=$(date date "+%d.%m.%Y") ` is a typo